# how to accurately reverse Geocode place names in swift/xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reverse-geocoding

Im stuck on a problem, I have location data stored as coordinates. I need a way to look up details for those coordinates.

Using CLGeocoder I am able get the address, however I need a way to find the name of the restaurant, shop, building etc accurately.

Otherwise I need to find the closest named establishment or a list of POIs close to the coordinates.

The coordinate are fairly close to POIs on apple maps but reverse geocoding through CLGeocoder returns nil for POIs nearby and does not find the name.

Comment: Use [GoogleSearchApi](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters) this gives you api like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch`

Comment: GoogleSearchApi is deprecated, is there a way of still using it? or something similar?

Comment: They have [Google Places SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start)

Comment: Apple maps are bad, they might work in USA but the rest of the world is very lousy... Switch everything to Google Maps, Google Places and so on... It is easier to use than the Apple maps and works faster and better in the whole world...

Comment: Are you saying that the Apple reverse geocoder gives you an empty list of place marks?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get the name of the place based on the longitude and latitude. We want to get the Hotel Name not just the address. The geocoder returns this. 

              //Code
print("\(location.coordinate.latitude)\n \(pm.name!),\(pm.subThoroughfare) \(pm.thoroughfare),\n \(pm.locality!), \(pm.postalCode!), \n \(pm.country!), \n \(pm.areasOfInterest) ")

                  //Output
643 Market St,Optional("643") Optional("Market St"),
 San Francisco, 94105, 
 United States, 
 nil